# sklearn MinMaxScaler that save rows and columns headers python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to normalize the df and saving the columns and rows index/headers.

```
      Sym1 Sym2 Sym3 Sym4
1     1    1    1    2
8     1    3    3    2
9     1    2    2    2
24    4    2    4    1


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), copy=True)
scaler.fit(df)
normData = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(df))
```

But i get countinus rows and coulmns:

```
      0    1    2    3
0     0    0    0    0.8
1     0    1    0.65 0.8
2     0    0.24 0.5  0.2
3     0.5  0.5  0.5  0.25
```

and i want a dataframe like this:

```
      Sym1 Sym2 Sym3 Sym4
1     0    0    0    0.8
8     0    1    0.65 0.8
9     0    0.24 0.5  0.2
24    0.5  0.5  0.5  0.25
```

what can I do?

Comment: you want the solution to be:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  1.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  1.        ],
         [ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.        ]]) ?

Comment: @sheldonzy no, i want the solution to be data frame.

Comment: So you only want to change the column name and index?

Comment: @sheldonzy I want to retain the column name and index.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you convert to DataFrame, you need to specify the desired column and index.

```
normData = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(df), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```